# Mysql & Laravel Multiple where clause on 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause, multiple-columns

I have a table having following 4 columns:

```
Id Name Activity Date
```

One name can have multiple entries as each time anyone takes any activity, it will be inserted with name, activity and that particular activity date.

I want to have a query where :

get all names who have done all following activities on mentioned dated

activity = run and date = 12/03/2015

activity = dance and date  = 10/01/2015

activity = read and date = 26/05/2015

Note that the activity combinations in where can change from minimum 1 to max 10-12

How can i do this effectively? also any better way doing it on mysql raw?

Answer (score 0):

You have three conditions, so if the number of the rows matching your conditions is the same, then get the name.

```
SELECT name, count(*) as match_count FROM names WHERE (name = 'run' AND 'date' = '12/03/2015') OR (name = 'dance' AND 'date' = '10/01/2015') OR (name = 'dance' AND 'read' = '26/05/2015') GROUP BY name

if($result->match_count == $numberOfConditions)
    $result->name
```

Or check it(the if statement) in your query

```
SELECT name, count(*) as match_count FROM names WHERE (name = 'run' AND 'date' = '12/03/2015') OR (name = 'dance' AND 'date' = '10/01/2015') OR (name = 'dance' AND 'read' = '26/05/2015') GROUP BY name HAVING match_count = 3
```

Comment: Thanks but I want something like And Where. So all those where clauses must match.

Comment: In your query it will give the results if any of the where clause is successful, I want to get names who has done all those activities and each activity has to be on that day only :|

Comment: Yes, its in multiple rows. So one name can have multiple entries each time a person does any activity. An EAV kind of table mappng.

Comment: Yes, @MeeraTank, the record should have entries for all the conditions

Comment: @MihirBhende It is better to make a change in your database design. Name hasMany Activity. Then you can do what you need easily using eloquent.

Comment: Currently I am using capsule outside to query the same database outside laravel as a different microservice, so not possible to chang ethe DB for now. But I would like to know how we can do this in mysql if we would keep eloquent aside?

Comment: Count you conditions, query database and count results, if they have the same count, then get the name.

Comment: would that be CPU intensive to do it? Also considering your eloquent advice, if I would have hasMany for names model to the activity model. But still how will I find if any name that has  the all where condition combinations?

Comment: You can also use `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` in your query.